# Symfony nginx virtual host

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have a virtual server with nginx, with my Symfony project installed in `/var/www/test`. In `/etc/nginx/site-avalible/test.conf` I create this config:

```
server {
server_name test.dev www.test.dev;
root /var/www/test/web;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}

location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/test_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/test_access.log;
}
```

and then create symlink:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf
```

and add rules to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       test.dev
```

this is all done in the server. Then I know the IP of my virtual server and I create in my local computer in `/etc/hosts`:

```
82.91.183.61    test.dev
```

and then try to open in my browser but have a 502 error, why? And how can I correct the virtual host config for nginx and how do I open my project in my local computer if I know the IP and can create a virtual host?

Comment: What does it log in `/var/log/nginx/test_error.log`? And does accessing `app.php` or `app_dev.php` directly produce a different response?

Comment: Post your error log